# ¿Como obtener semetral en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

tengo un registro de fechas dinamica y quiero obtener un rango de fecha semestral.

```
SELECT
date
FROM
    dates 
WHERE
date BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD('2018-10-11', INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) AND '2019-11-22'
GROUP BY MONTH(date)
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

Result:

```
**2019-04-11**
2019-05-01
2019-06-01
2019-07-01
2019-08-01
2019-09-01
**2019-10-01**
2019-11-01
```

y lo que deseo obtener es el sexto de cada mes.

Comment: Cual seria el problema? para que base de datos?

Comment: deseo obtener un reporte en la que la fecha salte 6 meses. estoy usando MYSQL

Comment: No entiendo muy bien para qué agrupas por meses y muestras date sin calcular ningún total por cada grupo. ¿Qué información quieres obtener de cada semestre? ¿Y de cada mes?